# I have done a small function, and, although the data inside looks correct, the answer appears as a promise, how to get it to answer me with data?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function that has to read from localstorage, in this function, I have written a few 'console.log' and they all appear with their data, instead when doing the 'return', it is telling me that I receive a promise ,,,, and bad

```
 static datosLogin() {
    let datos=localStorage.getItem('userWPR_TDA')
    console.log('datos',datos)
    let init =  JSON.parse( datos) 
    console.log('init',init)
    if (!AUTORIZAR) {
      init.role = 9
      init.id = ''
      init.token = ''
      init.tokemTda = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'
      init.userName = "Pruebas"
      init.local = "pruebas/Barconfinao)"
    }
    console.log('salgo',init)
    return init
  }
```

the call:

```
    let userA = LoginScreen.datosLogin()
    actUser(userA)
    console.log('fuera',userA)
```

the exit:

```
datos {"id":3,"role":9,"token":"e......}   LoginScreen.js:55 
init {id: 3, role: 9, token: "e......    LoginScreen.js:64 
salgo {id: 3, role: 9, token: "e..."...

**fuera Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}} Navbar.js:30 <---------------------------------------**
{NotLogged: true} Navbar.js:37
```

Why is he marking it as a promise ????

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are returning a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from your function.

If you want to get only the resolved data "The data after the promise if fulfilled"

You need to type [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```js
static async datosLogin(){
  // Your logic...

}


//Then...

let userA = await LoginScreen.datosLogin()
```

the await will wait for the promise to resolve and return the output of the function

Comment: But who generates promise?
In "salgo" I am showing the information that I return, and the data is fine .....